# number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length + several plots in same graph error

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot

I'm trying to draw several plots in the same graph in Rstudio, but to no avail. This is the code I'm using:

```
 for (i in 1:10){
  require(ggplot2)
  N <- 100 
  T <- 3
  Delta <- T/N
  B <- numeric(N+1)
  t <- seq(0,T,length=N+1)
  for(i in 2:(N+1)){
    B[i] <- B[i-1]+rnorm(1) * sqrt(Delta)
  }

  x <- 0
  y <- 3
  BB[i] <- x+B-(t/T)*(B[N+1]-y+x)

  df <- melt(data = BB, id.vars = "t")
  ggplot(data = df, aes(x = t, y = value, colour = variable)) + geom_line()

  }
```

Using ggplot2 as I seen recomended in several Stackoverflow post yieds "number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length".

I've seen several answers to that question but being quite a noob in R I  don't see how it applies to my  problem. Please and thank you in advance.

Comment: You're using the same index `i` in two different for loops. What kind of object is `BB`? If you define `BB` as a list and assign values to it using `BB[[i]]` maybe you'll get a better idea about what is going on. The error occurs in the `BB[i]` part of your code.

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
BB <- list()                                   # define BB as a list
for (i in 1:10){
    require(ggplot2)
    N <- 100 
    T <- 3
    Delta <- T/N
    B <- numeric(N+1)
    t <- seq(0,T,length=N+1)
    for(q in 2:(N+1)){                         # Change your index from i to q
        B[q] <- B[q-1]+rnorm(1) * sqrt(Delta)
    }

    x <- 0
    y <- 3
    BB[[i]] <- x+B-(t/T)*(B[N+1]-y+x)          # Assign each iteration to a list entry
}

# Exit the for loop
df <- as.data.frame(cbind(unlist(BB), # unlist the values in BB
                    rep(t,10), # define t variable by simply repeating it 
                    rep(1:10,each= 101))) # define loop id in a similar manner
names(df) <- c('value','t','variable') # give names to the variables
df$variable <- as.factor(df$variable) # turn variable into a factor
ggplot(data = df, aes(x = t, y = value, colour = variable)) + geom_line()
```

The resulting plot: 
[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Really helpful and now I realize where I did wrong. Thank you very much

Comment: You're welcome :). If you like the answer, could you please click ''accept'' (green check under the vote counter) and/or upvote?